# Flush Redis keys at the time of fail-back

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-redis-cache, disaster-recovery, azure-front-door

I am working on Disaster Recovery for my application deployed on Azure. I am using following architecture.
[image]

Left side of Azure front door is primary region and right side is secondary region. Suppose disaster happened in primary region then Azure front door will send data to secondary region Azure function. Now failback happened that means primary region is up now. I want to flush all keys from Redis for Primary region since it has stale data before Azure front door sending data to primary region azure function.
Azure front door is configured to send data to primary region if it is healthy otherwise secondry region Azure function.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: On a different note - you can set up the GEO replication of `Redis cache`--- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-geo-replication

Comment: With geo replication we would require Premium tier so cost would be high. We are using standard tier for cache.  second reason we need to remove geo replication link to write on secondary region cache which is manual work so avoiding Geo Replication